# "Всё одно" — просторечие?

Tags: лексика, просторечия

Выражение "всё одно" считается просторечием?

Comment: Если вам дан (или будет дан) исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 2):

Мнения составителей словарей разделились.

Фразеологический словарь:
[**Всё одно (едино)**](https://phraseology.academic.ru/1673/%D0%92%D1%81%D1%91_%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE_%28%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%29) — ***прост***., то же, что всё равно.

Толковый словарь (С. И. Ожегов, Н. Ю. Шведова): [весь](http://%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82.%D1%80%D1%84/%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C)
6. Всё равно — безразлично, одинаково, в любом случае. Всё одно (***прост.***) — то же, что всё равно. Всё едино (*устар. и ирон.*) — то же, что всё равно.

Толковый словарь (С. А. Кузнецов): [весь](https://gufo.me/dict/kuznetsov/%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C)
В значении наречия — *(разг*.) всё едино; (***разг.***) всё одно.

МАС: всё одно — ***прост.***, то же, что все равно.

Краткий справочник синонимов: всё едино, [всё одно](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%91%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE&all=x), всё равно [**без пометок**].

*А тебе завидовать крестьянству обидно. Это **все одно**, что горбатому завидовать.*
Ю. Тынянов. Кюхля

*Так, иногда подрабатываю на дому, кому приемник старый починю, кому ботинки залатаю. Но **все одно** копейки.*
П. Дашкова. Образ врага

*Как сущность Добро либо есть, либо его нет, так как сколько ни дели бесконечность — **всё одно** бесконечность останется (но так ли это?).*
А. Гоголев. Заратуштра

В пословицах и поговорках просторечность, конечно, присутствует.
(Все одно, что в лоб, что в голову. Все одно, что дерево, что бревно. По саже хоть гладь, хоть бей — все одно. Будто не все одно, что украл, что так унес.)

В современном же языке, как мне кажется, *всё одно* используется **целенаправленно, намеренно** — для придания особого смысла, для акцента на сказанном.
Ведь *всё равно* — это обычное, нейтральное, "многоупотребляемое" словосочетание,  а *всё одно* заставляет обращать внимание на фразу или предложение.

Answer (score 0):

В НКРЯ только в одном случае относится к диалектным, а во многих и многих других — к разговорным, преимущественно в составе прямой речи.

> По мне *всё одно*: антабус, автобус.  *Всё одно* взятка.  *Всё одно*, ничего
>   у вас не выйдет! ― кричу я. Не такие, конечно, но *всё одно* ― церква, с
>   колоколом.

(Сказанное никак не относится к фрагментам более пространных фразеологизмов: «всё одно и то же», «всё одно к одному».)

Comment: В дополнение к ответу скажу, что словари по этому вопросу расходятся во мнении: в "Толковом словаре" Кузнецова **всё одно** помечено как разговорное, у Ожегова — как просторечное, где-то ещё встречалась пометка "сниженное" (без др. пометок). По-видимому, в данном случае каждый вправе определять сам степень разговорности (я склонен считать его только *разговорным* из уважения к большому количеству народных пословиц).

Answer (score 0):

Согласно словарю, прилагательное "один" многозначно, и одно их его значений следующее. ОДИН 6. Тот же самый, такой же; одинаковый. Сидят за одной партой. Постройки одного типа. Люди одного поколения. Мы с вами одних лет.

Если оно используется в значении существительного, то возможны следующие варианты: Один к одному (одинаковы по качеству, размеру и т.п.). Мы с тобой хотим одного и того же.

Всё это нейтральный стиль. А  народность, разговорность, сниженность речи появляется,  когда слово остается "в одиночестве": не "одно и то же", а просто "одно". И мы получаем "всё одно" вместо "всё одно и то же" или вместо "всё равно".

Получается расширение области применения этой формы в данном значении, которое воспринимается как нечто новое, или как нечто упрощенное, свойственное народному языку. Появляется экспрессия, выразительность нестандартной формы, и это активно используется в современной речи.

А вот прогнозировать дальнейшее изменение стилевой принадлежности слова пока сложно.